# JQuery assigning a value to an input text via each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an each loop like so:

```
$.each(this, function (k, v) {

                        table += '<td><input type="text" name="' + k + '" id="' + k + '" /></td>';
                        $('#' + k).val(v);
                    });
```

What I am trying to do is populate the input type with what is in v, if I do:

```
table += '<td><input type="text" name="' + k + '" id="' + k + '" value="' + v + '" /></td>';
```

the value gets populated with the correct value, but when I submit my form, they are being submitted as empty strings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form").submit(function (event) {
        $.post("/api/update/", $("#form").serialize(), alert('success'));
    });
</script>
```

I dont know why `$('#' + k).val(v);` after the input is created is not working :(

Comment: You haven't created anything at that point.  You added a string to a string.  You haven't created anything on the DOM, so there will be nothing returned for `$('#' + k)` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Other than that, What's `this`..? what's the value of `k` and `v`?  How do we know whether those are empty or not..? If they are not empty, will `k` always be unique..?

Comment: Also, I think you meant to replace `alert('success')` with `function() { alert('success'); }`. Think about it: the way you've written it, the return value of `alert` is an argument to `$.post`, so it can't run `$.post` until `alert` has run. (Even though `alert` probably doesn't return anything anyway.) Even if you put the `alert` on a separate line after `$.post`, it will run after the request is sent but before the response is received, and therefore will do the alert even if the request subsequently fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add "/api/update/" as the "action" attribute for your form and get rid of your serialization logic, or (more likely what you were going for) put an

```
event.preventDefault()
```

at the top of your submit handler.

The issue is that your submit method by default submits the form, sending a request the form's "action" attribute, (in your case, likely the current page).  Thus, your browser creates an errant submit just before executing your $.post.